# Reading Camel Constant From Property file

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to read time delay from property file .

have defined in my property file :

```
time_inMilis=15000
```

I have configured my camel context xml to be :

```
    <bean id="property" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:/D:/Develop/resources/my.properties
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <camel:camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">   

     <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="file:/D:/Develop/resources/my.properties"/>

        <camel:route id="delayQueue">
            <camel:from uri="seda:queue1" />
            <delay asyncDelayed="true">
                <constant>${time_inMilis}</constant>
            </delay>
            <camel:to uri="seda:queue2" />
        </camel:route>

    </camel:camelContext>
```

camel do not throw any error but it seems that it ignores ${time_inMilis} and set 0 for my delay time.

What is the right way to read the delay constant from my property file ?

Answer (score 2):

First, it would be enough just to use *camel:propertyPlaceholder* instead of declaring bean *property*.

Second mistake is that you are using [Constant](http://camel.apache.org/constant.html) instead of [Simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) expression when trying to read your *time_inMilis* property value.

Third, when trying to get value of you property, you should specifically tell Camel that your are looking at properties.

If  your context defines propertiesPlaceholder like this:

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="props" location="classpath:/org/smp/eip/sample.properties"/>
    <package>org.apache.camel.example.spring</package>
</camelContext>
```

them with java DSL you'll be able to read the *textProeprty* value like this

```
from("file:src/data?noop=true")
    .transform().simple("Text read from properties: ${properties:textProperty}")
    .bean(new SomeBean());
```

Using Spring DSL from your original post, the correct way of reading property would be:

```
  <camel:route id="delayQueue">
        <camel:from uri="seda:queue1" />
        <delay asyncDelayed="true">
            <simple>${properties:time_inMilis}</simple>
        </delay>
        <camel:to uri="seda:queue2" />
    </camel:route>
```